# Magento 2: How to call REST Api from helper

Tags: magento2, rest-api

i have created REST Api how can i use those REST Api directly from helper?

Curl call is a option is there any other method that we can use?

Comment: We can directly use interfaces for communication between modules

Comment: can you please explain with example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally we need to use /V1/integration/customer/token to access token if we need to generate token internal purpose we can just use the interface directly as below:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Integration\Api\CustomerTokenServiceInterface $customerTokenService

) {
    $this->customerTokenService = $customerTokenService;

}

public function sample(string $email, string $password)
{

    $token = $this->customerTokenService->createCustomerAccessToken($email, $password);
}
```

in di.xml

```
 <route url="/V1/integration/customer/token" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\Integration\Api\CustomerTokenServiceInterface" method="createCustomerAccessToken"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

We can use Service class and method defined for any other APIS

Comment: How we can use that methods directly from helper?

Comment: You can Inject the interface in constructor and use the methods define in it